# Designing a FET switching circuit that fails open

Tags: mosfet, safety, failure

I'm trying to design a drive circuit for a car engine throttle valve. The valve is spring-loaded to close, and has a small DC motor for opening. (I'll also note that this only for my own vehicle.)

Below is my current shot at the thing. Motor stall current is roughly 3A at 12V. Microcontroller is a 3.3V device. The motor is to be controlled by PWM, but I have not yet experimented with it much. The circuit works otherwise fine, but as I burned the FET, it failed closed, forcing the valve fully open. From a quick internet search, failing closed is quite common for FETs. Needless to say, I'd like to avoid this "jammed fully open" -situation.

So, is there a circuit design or a specific FET that would fail open for certain?

(I'm not worrying too much about this particular failure, as the FET was not heatsinked and still had to dissipate ~1.5W of power)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPzDgX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I think the inrush-current causes the MOSFET to fail (i.e. short circuit). You shouldn't ask for a FET that "opens" on failure, because you cannot find one *(At least I didn't see any for about 10 years. If there's any chance for a MOSFET to be open-circuit on failure, please someone inform me.)*. Anyway, a series fuse *(as Jack Creasey suggested)* or a NTC (to prevent high inrush-currents) is what you need. Besides, if I were you, I would drive it with an N-Channel MOSFET since N-Ch ones are more common, cheaper, easier to find and have better performance compared to P-Ch siblings.

Comment: Ah, but shouldn't you ask for things you want to find out if they exist? Anyway, I agree the circuit should have been designed with N-Ch FETs. It's been a while, so I really can't say anymore why I decided to make it this way. As to why the FET failed in the first place, I suppose there is only a limited time a TO-220 can handle heat load of 1,5W without any cooling aids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the standard ways in functional safety when a disconnect function is done electronic is to have 2 or more series switches, so in case one fails you still have control and are able to change the system to a safe state. 
So in your case I would add a high side switch to the system so when the you detect that the system has fail, via feedback in your system, you switch off power to motor changing it to the safe state.

Comment: Thanks, I'll likely add a relay to the high side. In addition, it is a MT car, so even if everything electric fails, I still have couple of mechanical failsafes.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to ensure that power is released from a PWM solenoid throttle is to put a series fuse and blow that with a crowbar when you detect a fault ...you could use an SCR or a high current FET to blow the fuse.

I would suggest though that you consider buying either an existing cruise control or throttle servo with a clutch or magnetic coupling, they are much easier to control than the PWM solenoid.